# Outside connections to asp.net development webserver

Tags: asp.net, cassini

Is there any way to access my asp.net dev server (launched from visual studio) from an outside connection?  It seems to be filtered to only allow localhost

Comment: It's not actually IIS running the web server, but cassini; I have changed the tags accordingly.

Comment: What's this cassini mentioned by the post?

Comment: I get it now, UltiDev Cassini web server http://ultidev.com/Products/Cassini/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, cassini can only be accessed from the machine it is running on.

Answer (score 0):

CassiniDev, http://cassinidev.codeplex.com, can listen on any port/hostname